# Coco-applescript is in my documents folder. I am not a developer. Is it changing the way my apps work?

Tags: applescript, cocoa

I found Cocoa-AppleScript Applet 2.app in my documents folder. What is this? I noticed it when I was in iTunes and was going to add to my library. I just had to reinstall my OS because of problems and I do remember one of the problems was the iTunes would no longer open at all. I looked this Cocoa thing up and it said something about changing how things should work in iTunes. I don't want to have the same problem again.  I trust that things like that should be ok. I am not a developer and have no reason for this app.

Answer (score 1):

A Cocoa-AppleScript doesn't just appear in your documents folder. Someone put it there. With that said, it won't do anything if you don't run it. If you didn't make it, and if someone else uses your computer, I'd ask them what it's there for.